# Convert latex string into a formated literal string in java

Tags: java, latex

Using the import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXFormula;

I have the following code:

String formula = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the math formula ");

TeXFormula f = new TeXFormula(formula);

this converts my latex string into a formatted Latex object and the plugin lets me display it in a window using an icon, but I would like to display the formatted formula in a console string. The toString() method just gives me the objects hash. Is their a way to display it as a string using this object? Is their another plugin that would allow me to do this? Or do I have to create a string parser?

I tried using f.get(formula), f.toString() and f.VERSION

Comment: How did you envision a string like `E &= \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}` (from Wikipedia [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Example)) would show in a console? You can't really do that with pure text-based output, you need graphics. That's the point of LaTeX, to show the formula with graphics. Or did you want it printed as a computer formula like `E = (m * pow(c, 2)) / (sqrt(1 - (pow(v, 2) / pow(c, 2))))`? In what computer language?

Comment: I wanted it to be printed as a computer formula, and im using the java computer language